# Mapbox show area on hover over drawn polygon

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-draw

I am using the below code to add a custom control to draw the polygon on the map and show the area on the side(on a div) of the screen.

```
change() {
  this.map.on('load', () => {
      this.draw = new MapboxDraw({
        displayControlsDefault: false,
        controls: {
          polygon: true,
          trash: true
        }
      });
      this.map.addControl(this.draw);
      this.map.on('draw.create', (e) => {
        this.updateArea(e)
      });
      this.map.on('draw.delete', (e) => {
        this.updateArea(e)
      });
      this.map.on('draw.update', (e) => {
        this.updateArea(e)
      });
    }
  }
}
updateArea(e) {
  const data = this.draw.getAll();
  if (data.features.length > 0) {
    const area = turf.area(data);
    const rounded_area = Math.round(area * 100) / 100;
    this.selectedArea = rounded_area + ' sq m';
  } else {
    if (e.type === 'draw.delete') {
      this.selectedArea = '0 sq m';
      this.perimeter = '0 m';
    }
  }
  console.log(this.map.getStyle())
}
```

I want to display the area on the hover of the drawn polygon. And, I can also draw multiple polygons, so I need to show the popup with the area whenever I hover over the drawn polygon.

What I am not able to understand is, in which specific layer/source are these polygons drawn? I went over the 'mapbox-gl-draw' documentation,but there is no mention about the layer. I just found that when I console `this.map.getStyle()` as can be seen above, I get below object:

```
{
  center: (2)[0, 0],
  glyphs: "mapbox://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
  layers: (151)[{
    …}, ...],
  metadata: {
    mapbox: type: "default",
    mapbox: origin: "streets-v11",
    mapbox: autocomposite: true,
    mapbox: groups: {
      …}
  },
  name: "Mapbox Streets",
  sources: {
    composite: {
      …},
    contour: {
      …},
    geojson: {
      …},
    orthomosaic: {
      …},
    dsm: {
      …},
    …
  },
  sprite: "mapbox://sprites/mapbox/streets-v11",
  version: 8,
  zoom: 3,
}
```

So, I see in the browser console that sources in this above object contain the `mapbox-gl-draw-hot` and `mapbox-gl-draw-cold` sources. And they contain the active and stale drawn polygons(and their corresponding feature data), but how do I use that data to enable popups on the map that will show me the corresponding area on hovering. I tried playing around with the id of the generated polygon in these sources, but with no luck.

Any suggestions welcome.